# Unable to instantiate application - AndroidManifest settings

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk

We have recently developed an Android app and published it via Google Play. First of all we created a beta test group, added members to it and got feedback etc from each and everyone of them. We had no problems publishing and installing this beta version on the users devices.

We promoted this beta version (API level 14+) to production and suddenly the app started to fail after installing with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application x.x.x.App:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: x.x.x.App
```

In the AndroidManifest file the name attribute of Application was the full packagename x.x.x.App. We changed this to be just the class name App and everything started to work smoothly.

However the customer decided to make the app compatible with API 10 - 13 and we made the changes to AndroidManifest file accordingly. We just changed the minSDK=10. Again we had the beta testing process with no further errors etc.

We then decided to promote this app to production and now we get the same error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application x.x.x.App:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: x.x.x.App
```

again when installing/upgrading to this new version.

What on earth is going on here - I need an explanation (if it exists) since I am not able to find any meaning of this?

EDIT: The manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.expatindenmark.adquota"
    android:versionCode="8"
    android:versionName="3.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="App"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_hoejtid_ikon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.expatindenmark.adquota.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="locale"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.expatindenmark.adquota.AdquotaTabActivity"
            android:configChanges="locale"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
     </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your manifest file...

Comment: is there any changes you have made in previous manifest or cirtificate.

Comment: The only thing we changed in the new version was minSDK - exchanging 14 with 10.

Comment: @PiyushGupta Okay - I changed name = "App" to name = ".App" and now it works. This is very annoying and the lack of consistency is scary! I still need some kind of explanation why this issue occurs in an app already in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in an earlier comment I changed name = "App" to name = ".App" and that works.